# Constructing a biorthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd to approximate a signal from a sum of 3 guassian functions

$f(x) = a_0 \exp(-(x - 1)^2) + a_1 \exp(-x^2) + a_2 \exp(-(x + 1)^2)$

My space is $\mathbb{R}^1$ and my frame consists of the 3 guassian functions each offset from each other.

Given some function $f$ I'd like to be able to determine the coefficients that best approximate $f$ using my gaussian frame. I believe I need to construct the biorthogonal basis for my 3 gaussians but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\psi_i(x), 1 \le i \le n$ be your $n$ (linearly independent) basis functions, assume each one is square integrable ($\psi_i \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, this is an important assumption because $L^2$ is an Hilbert space, with an inner product).

If $f$ is in the span of those $n$ functions : $f = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \psi_i$, finding the coefs $a_i$ is a matrix problem.

Let $$b_i = \langle f,\psi_i \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \psi_i(x) dx$$ and $$M_{i,j} = \langle \psi_i,\psi_j \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi_j(x) \psi_i(x) dx$$ then $$a = M^{-1} b$$ (i.e. $a_j = \sum_{i=1}^n M^{-1}_{j,i} b_i$) Do you see why ?

Finally, the [biorthogonal family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biorthogonal_system) is $\phi_j = \sum_{i=1}^n M^{-1}_{j,i} \psi_i$, so that $$\langle \psi_k,\phi_j \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n M^{-1}_{j,i} \langle \psi_i,\psi_k \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n M^{-1}_{j,i} M_{i,k} = \delta_{k,j}$$

and this is useful because it allows us to find the coefficients $a_i$ even when $f = g + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \psi_i$ whenever $g$ lies in the complementary subspace of $span(\{\psi_i\})$, i.e. whenever $\langle g, \psi_i \rangle = 0$

Comment: How do you get $a = M^{-1}b$ ? I don't see the jump to that

Comment: @coderdave  simply write $b_j =\langle \psi_j , f\rangle =    \langle \psi_j,\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \psi_i \rangle =  \sum_{i=1}^n a_i  \langle \psi_j,\psi_i \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n M_{ji} a_i$ so that in matrix-vector notation $b= M a$

Comment: thank you - this has answered my question. However, while I see how you got through all the equations and each step makes sense I don't think I would have ever figured this out. I don't see the motivation for constructing $M_{i,j}$ to begin with.

Comment: @coderdave  don't worry, after a while you will think that considering the matrix $M_{i,j} = \langle \psi_i,\psi_j \rangle$ (and its inverse $M^{-1}$) is very natural, in signal processing you will see it often : under the name  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix related to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_matrix and the covariance matrix